# A Problem Concerning Odd Perfect Number

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

Briefly, prove that every odd number having only three distinct prime factors cannot be a perfect number.
I know there are results much stronger than the one above, but I am looking for an answer without computer cracking (which means the computation can be carried out by a person), thanks.

Comment: This is easy to do directly. No computer is necessary. The only cases that requires some thought are  $\{p,q,r \} = \{3,5,7\}$ and $\{p,q,r \} = \{3,5,11 \}$ because otherwise we have $\frac{p}{p-1}\frac{q}{q-1}\frac{r}{r-1} <2$ for odd primes $p,q,r.$

Comment: I get this too. And I don't know what to do next. Can you help me deal with the situations remaining?

Comment: Already Sylvester has shown in $1888$ that $t\ge 5$ for the number $t$ of prime factors of an odd perfect number, by elementary means.

Comment: Don't you also need to look at {3,5,13}?

Comment: http://math.byu.edu/~pace/NotEight_web.pdf Here is a finer result, but it seems to require computers' help.

Comment: @Anthony Quas: Yes, thanks, you do, I thought I had made an extra comment to add that correction, but I must not have saved it properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proof, perhaps not the simplest. Let $n$ be an odd perfect number with three distinct prime factors. As observed in the comments, $n$ is of the form $3^a5^bp^c$, where $p\in\{7,11,13\}$.

It is a simple fact (observed by Euler) that exactly one of the exponents $a$, $b$, $c$ is odd. Let $q^r\parallel n$ be the corresponding prime power (i.e. $r$ is odd), then $q+1$ divides $\sigma(q^r)$, hence also $\sigma(n)=2n$. Therefore $(q+1)/2$ divides $n/q^r$, which forces $q\not\in\{3,7,11,13\}$, i.e. $q=5$. Hence $b$ is odd, while $a$ and $c$ are even. Now we can rewrite the equation $\sigma(n)=2n$ as
$$ 3^{a-1}5^bp^c=(1+3+\dots + 3^a)(1+5^2+\dots + 5^{b-1})(1+p+\dots+p^c),$$
where the middle sum on the right hand sum only contains even powers of $5$. In particular, $5$ divides $1+3+\dots + 3^a$ or $1+p+\dots+p^c$. The first possibility is excluded by $a$ even. Similarly, the second possibility is excluded for $p\in\{7,13\}$ by $c$ even, whence $p=11$. Now the condition becomes
$$ 3^{a-1}5^b11^c=(1+3+\dots + 3^a)(1+5^2+\dots + 5^{b-1})(1+11+\dots+11^c).$$
Looking at this equation modulo $4$, we get $3\equiv (b+1)/2\pmod{4}$, i.e. $b\equiv 5\pmod{8}$. In particular, $b\geq 5$. Combining this with
$$ \frac{5}{3}=\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{3^a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{5^{b-1}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{11}+\dots+\frac{1}{11^c}\right),$$
we get that
$$ \frac{5}{3}>\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{3^a}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{5^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11^2}\right).$$
This shows that $a<4$, i.e. $a=2$. Hence $\sigma(3^a)=13$ divides $\sigma(n)=2n=2\cdot 3^a5^b11^c$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh my last comment made a mistake, your answer is completely correct! Thanks for the answer, it's simple enough.

Comment: @Uloser: For $a=4$ the sum is $121$. In general, for $a\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ the sum is $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, while for $a\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ the sum is $\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault.